# how can I get variable from javascript using flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

So I have set up app.py, index.js, index.html in appropriate folder as flask suggests. Index.html gets rendered as when app.py runs then index.html runs index.js which grabs input data from user. I am trying to send this input and send it to python where I can call an API, grab data, and work with it however I cannot think of a way to do this.

my app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

# This will run upon entrance
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/stock_data")
def get_stock_data():
    # called from index.js Plot function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
console.log("everythin works fine.")
d3.select("#stocklabelsubmit").on("click", submitted)

function submitted(){
    d3.event.preventDefault();

    // grab label inputted.
    var inputted_label = d3.select("#stockInput").node().value;

    d3.select("#stockInput").node().value = "";

    Plot(inputted_label);
};


function Plot(input){
    var url = "full url"
    // when this function is called call /stock_data function!!
    // data is what is returned from python
    d3.json(url).then(function(data){

    })
}
```

Everything works fine, when I console log inputted_label at the end of function submitted it works. Now I want to send inputted_label variable to /stock_data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var url` needs to be a full, valid URL, not just the path to the flask endpoint.

Comment: okay, if I set full url how to use input in app.py?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "/stock_data"
```

This needs to be a valid URL, not just the path to the Flask endpoint. That means it must start with "http://" or "https://" and include a domain. For development purposes, `"http://localhost/stock_data"` will work. If you ever deploy this to a server, you will want to create a configuration file so that the host name can be configured depending on what environment you are running in.

Comment: Why create a config file when `"{{ url_for(some_endpoint) }}"` is built for this?

Comment: @roganjosh That depends on how the JavaScript file is served. If it is served from Flask, then sure.

Comment: Passed the discussion to chat because I think I'm missing something

Comment: Then how do I use input in python? just call "input"?

Comment: @makewhite You don't use `input()` in a web app.

Comment: @makewhite If you need to pass data from the JavaScript code to the `/stock_data` endpoint, you should do a POST request and send JSON in the body.

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: @makewhite No. I'm sure there are many ways. However, you have to keep in mind that a web app will generally run two pieces of code on two completely different machines that are connected on the Internet. The JS code runs in a browser on your local machine while the Python Flask code runs on a server that can be thousands of miles away. This is why you can't use `input()`. The user has no terminal on the server so they cannot see the prompt nor type in anything.

Comment: @makewhite I suggest that you start by learning about POST. Once you have a handle on that, then you can learn about the other HTTP verbs and when to use them.